# What is causing Eggplant performance tool to capture irrelevant URLs during recording?

Tags: testing, url, load, performance-testing, egg

I am facing an issue while recording: the tool is not capturing the desired URL. For example, when I try to record `amazon.com`, it captures an irrelevant URL instead of the correct one. Could you please assist me in resolving this issue?
[image: Amazon Eggplant recording]

Eggplant Performance records HTTP traffic. I use this to record and play back HTTP request for load testing. However, currently it is only recording request to Microsoft domains. I have been using Google Chrome as my browser.